# How to get the properties of json object in C#?

Tags: c#, json

I am getting the json (objArr) object using the following code:

```
var objArr = (object[])record.Value;
```

The code at runtime looks like this:

[image]
The json object `objArr` contains the list of rows, how can I retrieve the properties of rows?

I am able to list the properties with the following loop:

```
 foreach (var obj in objArr)
 {                       
      foreach(var item in (Dictionary<string, object>)obj)
      {                            

      }
 }
```

but I want to retrieve the properties directly from `objArr`

Comment: Where is your JSON?

Comment: it is not json string it is object(objArr)

Comment: what is your problem then?

Comment: can i get the properties of objects directly from the object without looping the object

Comment: What is the type of your object? What properties do you want to get?

Comment: @rakshi: No, you can't because objArr is an array of `Dictionary<string, object>` so you will have to iterate through it one way or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this according to your onject specification

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();  
BlogSites blogObject = js.Deserialize<BlogSites>(jsonData);  
string name = blogObject.Name;  
string description = blogObject.Description;  

// Other way to whithout help of BlogSites class  
dynamic blogObject = js.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonData);  
string name = blogObject["Name"];  
string description = blogObject["Description"];
```

you can refer [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/json-serialization-and-deserialization-in-c-sharp/)